# Watson Assistant Extract multiple pattern entities

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have an entity defined as

```
@code
- @code:type_1 = pattern 'Y(\d{3})'
- @code:type_2 = pattern 'order number(\d{3})'
- @code:type_3 = pattern 'CZ(\d{3})'
```

I am trying to capture the following context values like so

```
{
  "context": {
    "type_3s": "<? @code.filter(\"c\", \"c['value'] == 'type_3'\").joinToArray('%e.groups[1]%') ?>"
  }
}
```

So that for input

`Please delete codes CZ123, CZ456, and CZ789`, my final context looks like this:
`$type_3s =[123,456,789]`

Currently getting the error

```
SpEL evaluation error: Expression [ entities['code'].filter("c", "c['value'] == 'type_3'").joinToArray('%e.groups[1]%') ] at position 63: EL1004E: Method call: Method joinToArray(String) cannot be found on ArrayList type
```

In the above example, code.values evaluates to:

```
@code.values =["type_3", "type_3", "type_3"]
```

Any help in achieving the desired context would be greatly appreciated, thank you so much!

Comment: Could you add how `@code.values` looks like, i.e. its value?

Comment: @data_henrik `@code.values` for the above string would be
`@code.values = ["type_3", "type_3", "type_3"] `

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to take a look at the [Watson Assistant entity syntax](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language#expression-language-access-entity). `.value` returns the identified entity which would be **type_3**. You would need to use `.literal` to access what was really entered.

In the tutorial on [building a database-driven Slackbot](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/solution-tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-slack-chatbot-database-watson) a similar method is used to access what was entered for a location entity. The code is on GitHub.